# Url mapping in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to do url mapping using coding in asp.net c#

if /default.aspx page is requested then on client site it should be shown /default.
asp.net(c#) 4.0 .net framework

Comment: that is call url rewriting. this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx might help you

Comment: what version of ASP.Net do you use?

Answer (score 3):

[From Scott Guthrie Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

**Mapping URLs using ASP.NET Web Forms**

ASP.NET 4.0 now allows you to also use the URL Routing engine to map URLs to ASP.NET Web Forms pages as well as ASP.NET MVC Controllers.

Below is an example of how you can use the new MapPageRoute() helper method in ASP.NET 4.0 to map the `/default` URL to a `default.aspx` page that lives immediately under the application root directory:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

    routes.MapPageRoute(
    "default-page",
    "default",
    "~default.aspx"
    );
}
void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: i am using simple web form project not MVC

Comment: @juhi, did you read the article? It has url rewrite for MVC and Webforms as well. I chosen webforms and answered here

Answer (score 0):

You may like to check this  [Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) and [Managed Fusion URL Rewriter and Reverse Proxy](http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/). Also check this example:- [An Example of URL Rewriting With ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641758/An-Example-of-URL-Rewriting-With-ASP-NET)

Also check out the [Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.friendlyurls%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) to easily use routing and get friendly urls